# How often do I need do get a a Spreadsheet via e.g. .openbyID vs. .getActiveSheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I am new to google app script and I was thinking about how to avoid makeing excess calls to a google spreadsheet in my app. 
If I open a Spreadsheet within a function like this:
`var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("id");`
How long can I acces this sheet by 
`var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadSheet();`  Just within the function? 
And is the second variant actually helpful in speeding up my script?

I could of course declare the second var as a global but I would only do that if it would benefical (encapsulation etc.)

Answer (score 1):

I am not exactly an expert, but as far as I know, the second call is absolutely redundant. With openbyid you do have all you need to work with the spreadsheet. It remains open until your script is over.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it for as long as the variable exists in its scope. You cant serialize it.
If you put it in a global it will work too. Remember that the global will be reset on the next script call, they dont persist in between requests.
I doubt getActiveSpreadsheet will be any different than opening by id.